# i have installed sql developer but can't run?

Tags: java, sqldeveloper

It doesn't work and give me this message:

> Type the full pathname of a JDK installation (or Ctrl-C to quit), the path will be stored in `/home/muhammad/.sqldeveloper/4.1.0/product.conf`

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to install `Oracle JDK 8` (`Oracle Java SE Development Kit 8`) in order to make it work: you can get the latest version [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html), or you can download it from the `webupd8` `Java` repository:

1. Add the `webupd8` `Java` repository to `apt`: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java`
2. Update the `apt` cache: `sudo apt-get update`
3. Install `Oracle JDK 8`: `sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer`

Then when prompted for a `JDK` installation provide the `Oracle JDK 8` installation path, which is either the path you chose during the manual installation or the default path for the version installed via the `webupd8` repository, which is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have been trying to solve this problem since the last 6 hours !!